# Redirect All Routing Errors to Root URL of the Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, exception, routes

For example typing: `localhost:3000/absurd-non-existing-route`
How do I get invalid routes to point to the main page of the application in Rails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [rescue_from](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html) in your `ApplicationController` to rescue `ActionController::RoutingError` and redirect to the home page when it happens.

This will not work in Rails 3 currently. [A ticket has been filed.](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4444-can-no-longer-rescue_from-actioncontrollerroutingerror)

Answer (score 7):

On **Rails 4**+

Edit your `routes.rb` file by adding a `get "*path", to: redirect('/')` line just above the last `end` as mentioned by user @ [Rails: redirect all unknown routes to root_url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132039/rails-redirect-all-unknown-routes-to-root-url)

Answer (score 6):

[The solution presented here](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/36-rails-3-0-rescue-from-routing-error-solution) works pretty well

```
#Last route in routes.rb
match '*a', :to => 'errors#routing'

# errors_controller.rb
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
  def routing
    render_404
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's something I came up with trying to find a universal catch-all solution for routing exceptions. It handles most popular content types.

#### config/applicaiton.rb

```
config.exceptions_app = routes
```

#### routes.rb

```
match '/404', to: 'errors#show', via: :all, code: 404
```

#### ErrorsController

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
  layout false

  # skipping CSRF protection is required here to be able to handle requests for js files
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  respond_to :html, :js, :css, :json, :text

  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render code.to_s, status: code }
      format.js   { head code }
      format.css  { head code }
      format.json { render json: Hash[error: code.to_s], status: code }
      format.text { render text: "Error: #{ code }", status: code }
    end
  end

  private

  def code
    params[:code]
  end
end
```

The `ErrorsController` is designed to be more universal, to handle all kind of errors.

It is advised to create your own view for the 404 error in `app/views/errors/404.html`.

Comment: You answer is great, but I would add:

-> Add custom error handler in application.rb:

# File: config/application.rb:
`config.exceptions_app = self.routes` and change the route to `get '404', :to => "errors#show", code: 404` otherwise Active Storage does not load files or images.

Answer (score 1):

**If you are using rails 3**,
 

Use the following solution

In your `routes.rb`, add the following line in the end of the file

> match "*path" => "controller_name#action_name", via: [:get, :post]

---

And in your Controller, add

```
def action_name
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

**If you are using rails 4**

Write this line in your `routes.rb`

```
match '*path' => redirect('/'), via: :get
```