# Rails: redirect all unknown routes to root_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, routes, url-routing

Whenever a user hits the wrong page, rails shows 404.html from the public folder. However, I'd like just to redirect the browser to the root page, without showing anything. So I tried globbing, but came to no avail, it still shows the 404 page. Here's an extract from my routes file:

```
# ...
map.root :controller => 'home', :action => 'home'
map.connect '*', :controller => 'home', :action => 'home'
```

Any suggestions? Thanks, guys!

Comment: I assume you have a 'home_controller' which contains the 'home' action which says something like render :nothing => true?

Comment: No. There is a home action in the home controller and there is also a home view (home.html.erb).

Answer (score 79, accepted):

If your project is powered by rails 3, add simply this line to your routes.rb

```
match '*path' => redirect('/')
```

Edit: If you're on Rails 4 or 5

```
match '*path' => redirect('/'), via: :get
```

or

```
get '*path' => redirect('/')
```

Comment: Thanks! Well, it's Rails 2.3.10

Comment: Thanks a *lot*, man! It did it. That's how I did it in rails 2: `map.connect '*path', :controller => 'home', :action => 'home'` So, it's the `'*path'` that was the key to the whole thing. Thanks again :-)

Comment: You can also use `get` instead of `match`, which is just shorthand for adding `via: :get`.

Comment: Make sure to put this at the bottom of your routes list.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for valid routes with invalid ids (e.g. `root.com/articles/293`, where 293 is a non-existent article id in your database)

Comment: Well that's because route was matched and that's all that router is concerned about. You need to do additional check in your controller to see if the article with the provided ID exists.

Comment: I'd like to point out that "or" should not be part of the code block in this answer.  Should be
`match '*path' => redirect('/'), via: :get`
or
`get '*path' => redirect('/')`

Answer (score 21):

Like the answer by Arkan. One point, if do not want this behaviour in development environment, then could do -

```
match '*path' => redirect('/')   unless Rails.env.development?
```

Answer (score 11):

Rails 4-

(**routes.rb**)

You can still use a simple `get` to redirect all unknown routes.

```
  get '*path', to: 'home#index'
```

If you wish to provide routing to both POST and GET requests you can still use match, but Rails wants you to specify the request method via `via`.

```
  match "*path" => "home#index", via: [:get, :post]
```

Remember that `routes.rb` is executed sequentially (matching the first route that fits the supplied path structure), so put wildcard catching at the bottom of your matchings.

Comment: Thank you for the notice of putting it at the bottom.

Comment: Does this still work?  Doesn't seem to work in my Rails 4 app.

Comment: I have a problem in rails 5 where the `get '*path', to: 'searches#new'` results in 406 errors for all uploaded images in my app.

Answer (score 9):

There seems to be a bug in rails 5.2 where active_storage routes are picked up by the catchall route, resulting in broken links to uploaded images.  The issue has been reported in the rails repo on github, and someone commented with the below patch until the bug gets fixed in a new release:

In `routes.rb` right before last `end`

```
get '*all', to: 'application#index', constraints: lambda { |req|
    req.path.exclude? 'rails/active_storage'
  }
```

then in the application controller add:

```
def index
  flash.notice = 'No page found at that address'
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Comment: also, you can add catch-all route after application initialization, as described here: 
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/671#issuecomment-1780159

Comment: This answer is the way to go in Rails 6 with ActiveStorage

Answer (score 1):

You need create a controller to do that

```
class RedirectsController 

  def index
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

And in your routes

```
map.connect '*', :controller => 'redirects', :action => 'index'
```

Comment: Is this answer for Rails 3 as well?

Comment: Works with rails 3 too. You just need change the ligne with match. See globing in routing guides