# How to create a catch-all route in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to have all requests that satisfy a certain constraint to go to a specific controller. So I need a catch-all route. How do I specify that in Rails? Is it something like this?

```
match '*', to: 'subdomain_controller#show', constraints: {subdomain: /.+\.users/}
```

Will that really catch all possible routes? It's important that none slip through even if there are many nested directories.

Using Ruby on Rails 3.2, but ready to upgrade to 4.0.

***UPDATE***: `'*path'` seems to work. However, the issue I'm running into is whenever the file exists in my `public` directory, Rails renders that instead.

Comment: I think this question is answered here:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132039/rails-redirect-all-unknown-routes-to-root-url][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132039/rails-redirect-all-unknown-routes-to-root-url

Comment: @ksu - so it's `*path`? And then `params[:path]` holds the path?

Answer (score 19):

I think you need minor tweaks in this approach but you get the point:

UPDATE:

```
#RAILS 3
#make this your last route.
match '*unmatched_route', :to => 'application#raise_not_found!'

#RAILS 4, needs a different syntax in the routes.rb. It does not accept Match anymore.
#make this your last route.
get '*unmatched_route', :to => 'application#raise_not_found!'
```

And

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

...
#called by last route matching unmatched routes.  
#Raises RoutingError which will be rescued from in the same way as other exceptions.
def raise_not_found!
    raise ActionController::RoutingError.new("No route matches #{params[:unmatched_route]}")
end
...

end
```

More info here:  https://gist.github.com/Sujimichi/2349565

Comment: This doesn't work for root paths or paths that exist in the `public` directory. Root paths are not a big deal, I can add a `root to` in my routes file. But the other issue I don't know how to overcome.

Comment: In Rails 4 it gives me error: rake aborted!
You should not use the `match` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method. If you want to expose your action to both GET and POST, add `via: [:get, :post]` option. If you want to expose your action to GET, use `get` in the router: Instead of: match "controller#action"
Do: get "controller#action"

Comment: Yes I think, Rails 4 needs a different syntax in the routes.rb. It does not accept Match anymore.

get '*unmatched_route', :to => 'application#raise_not_found!'

Comment: Rails 4 does accept match, but you need to also specify the HTTP method. Catch-all that redirects to root is `match "*path", to: redirect('/'), via: :all`

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
Calamas::Application.routes.draw do
  get '*path', to: 'subdomain_controller#show',constraints: lambda { |request| request.path =~ /.+\.users/ }
end
```

Comment: Haven't tried this, but looks like it might be confusing to have `:subdomain` as the path? Is the constraint on the path or the subdomain then?

Comment: My previous answer wouldn't have worked in your case. See my updated answer. Documentation here -> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints

Comment: This doesn't work for root paths or paths that exist in the `public` directory. Root paths are not a big deal, I can add a root to in my routes file. But the other issue I don't know how to overcome.