# Why can't I start the Rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is my console log:

```
Last login: Thu Feb 9 14:24:17 on ttys000
leon$ cd Sites
leon$ ll
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 501 20 136 6 Feb 15:15 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 22 501 20 748 9 Feb 14:24 ..
-rw-r--r--@ 1 501 20 6148 9 Feb 14:12 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x 19 501 20 646 6 Feb 15:15 simple_cms
leon$ cd simple_cms
leon$ ll
total 80
drwxr-xr-x 19 501 20 646 6 Feb 15:15 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 501 20 136 6 Feb 15:15 ..
-rw-r--r--@ 1 501 20 8196 9 Feb 13:54 .DS_Store
-rw-r--r-- 1 501 20 468 6 Feb 15:12 .gitignore
-rw-r--r-- 1 501 20 1899 6 Feb 15:12 Gemfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 501 20 4280 6 Feb 15:12 Gemfile.lock
-rw-r--r-- 1 501 20 374 6 Feb 15:12 README.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 501 20 227 6 Feb 15:12 Rakefile
drwxr-xr-x 11 501 20 374 6 Feb 16:39 app
drwxr-xr-x 8 501 20 272 6 Feb 15:12 bin
drwxr-xr-x 15 501 20 510 6 Feb 16:22 config
-rw-r--r-- 1 501 20 130 6 Feb 15:12 config.ru
drwxr-xr-x 3 501 20 102 6 Feb 15:12 db
drwxr-xr-x 4 501 20 136 6 Feb 15:12 lib
drwxr-xr-x 5 501 20 170 9 Feb 14:12 log
drwxr-xr-x 11 501 20 374 6 Feb 16:39 public
drwxr-xr-x 9 501 20 306 6 Feb 15:12 test
drwxr-xr-x 8 501 20 272 6 Feb 16:03 tmp
drwxr-xr-x 4 501 20 136 6 Feb 15:40 vendor
leon$ rails server
/Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:51: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:52: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run rails server -h for more startup options
/Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:138: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
Exiting
/Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:78:in check_via': You should not use thematchmethod in your router without specifying an HTTP method. (ArgumentError) If you want to expose your action to both GET and POST, addvia: [:get, :post]option. If you want to expose your action to GET, usegetin the router: Instead of: match "controller#action" Do: get "controller#action" from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1902:inmap_match'
from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1599:in match' from /Users/leon/Sites/simple_cms/config/routes.rb:5:inblock in <top (required)>'
from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:389:in instance_exec' from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:389:ineval_block'
from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:371:in draw' from /Users/leon/Sites/simple_cms/config/routes.rb:1:in<top (required)>'
from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in load' from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:inblock in load'
from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in load_dependency' from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:inload'
from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in block in load_paths' from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:ineach'
from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in load_paths' from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:inreload!'
from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in block in updater' from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:77:inexecute'
from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in updater' from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:inexecute_if_updated'
from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:119:in block in <module:Finisher>' from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:ininstance_exec'
from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in run' from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:inblock in run_initializers'
from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:228:in block in tsort_each' from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:350:inblock (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:431:in each_strongly_connected_component_from' from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:349:inblock in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in each' from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:incall'
from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in each_strongly_connected_component' from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:226:intsort_each'
from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:205:in tsort_each' from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:inrun_initializers'
from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in initialize!' from /Users/leon/Sites/simple_cms/config/environment.rb:5:in<top (required)>'
from /Users/leon/Sites/simple_cms/config.ru:3:in require_relative' from /Users/leon/Sites/simple_cms/config.ru:3:inblock in
'
from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in instance_eval' from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:ininitialize'
from /Users/leon/Sites/simple_cms/config.ru:in new' from /Users/leon/Sites/simple_cms/config.ru:in'
from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in eval' from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:innew_from_string'
from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in parse_file' from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:318:inbuild_app_and_options_from_config'
from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:218:in app' from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:59:inapp'
from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:353:in wrapped_app' from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:124:inlog_to_stdout'
from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:77:in start' from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:inblock in server'
from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in tap' from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:inserver'
from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in run_command!' from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in<top (required)>'
from /Users/leon/Sites/simple_cms/bin/rails:9:in require' from /Users/leon/Sites/simple_cms/bin/rails:9:in<top (required)>'
from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in load' from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:incall'
from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in call' from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:inrun'
from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/bin/spring:49:in <top (required)>' from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:inload'
from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in <top (required)>' from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:inrequire'
from /Users/leon/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in require' from /Users/leon/Sites/simple_cms/bin/spring:15:in<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:3:in load' from bin/rails:3:in'
leon$
```

I also posted it on GitHub since I was having troubles posting code here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28012.

I am following a Lynda tutorial, and I can't move past the getting Ruby on Rails set up because of this error.

Comment: Also a contributor posted 'The fallback match route' in comment to my routes.rb. Please advise me in how i should properly structure my routes.rb Thanks again.

Comment: Select the code and click on the codeblock icon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 4: You should not use the \`match\` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798466/rails-4-you-should-not-use-the-match-method-in-your-router-without-specifying)

Comment: Also, FWIW, you can just paste in your code, highlight it, ans click the code button ( looks like {}) in the editor...

Comment: Also, if you also don't feel like pressing the code button, Ctrl-K works.

Comment: A third way to paste code: paste your code into your desktop text editor, select all, tab once (it will indent), copy, then paste here.

Comment: Pro tips for posting: keep it succinct. You _can_ mention you are new in the body, but it's too verbose in the title. Just keep to the facts. Too much negative information about your programming problems may put people off helping, so just stick to code, errors, useful info. If you don't like a feature of Stack Overflow, post on Meta, not here, since complaints here just create work for volunteer editors.

Comment: @Sameer: regarding your helpful edits, if you see material that is not really relevant to the question, you can just delete it. See my later edit! Thanks for your work.

Answer (score 1):

From your stack you can see that you have an error in `simple_cms/config/routes.rb` at line 5.

At the top of the log you read the reason:

> You should not use the match method in your router without specifying an
>   HTTP method.
>
> (ArgumentError) If you want to expose your action to both
>   GET and POST, add via: [:get, :post] option.
>
> If you want to expose your
>   action to GET, use get in the router:
>
> Instead of: match
>   "controller#action" Do: get "controller#action"

you can find more documentation on how to structure your `routes.rb` file in the [Official Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: after implementing get it seemed to solve my issue. Thanks heaps. I've been at this for 2 days!

Comment: @lee if this fixed your problem, you should mark this as the accepted answer. Helps others who come after you find it. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: @lee: to accept an answer, click on the tick mark adjacent to the answer, so that it turns green. It is how we thank people on Stack Overflow.