# How to rescue page not found 404 in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception

How to rescue page not found if user add wrong url in rails. I hope to show 404 page present in public folder if the url is invalid. How to do that? I was browsing about it but could not find a solution. I tried many ways to fix the problem, but they don't seem to be working. 
I am stuck here, please help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

i found the solution, check this out => http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/36-rails-3-0-rescue-from-routing-error-solution (great solution)

routes.rb :

```
# at the end of you routes.rb
match '*a', :to => 'errors#routing', via: :get
```

errors_controller.rb :

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
  def routing
    render_404
  end
end
```

application.rb :

```
rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, :with => :render_404

 private
  def render_404(exception = nil)
    if exception
        logger.info "Rendering 404: #{exception.message}"
    end

    render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", :status => 404, :layout => false
  end
```

Comment: It would be nice if it could this handle be generic to handle other mime types. Like non-exist.js or does-not-exists.xml

Comment: @Ismael did you find something about js or xml format files?

Comment: I did not get involved anymore about this issue. But i think it is related to respond_to function, very easy to understand, check it out.

Answer (score 32):

Solution for **Rails 4**

On *routes.rb*:

```ruby
get '*unmatched_route', to: 'application#not_found'
```

On *application_controller.rb*:

```ruby
def not_found
  # Your exception handling code here
end
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer and this comment (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368799/how-to-create-a-catch-all-route-in-ruby-on-rails#comment44283169_19369372) I was able to make a "catch all Not Found errors". ^_^