# RSpec 404 test respond with status 200

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I've written a test to test the 404 page

**pages_controller_spec.rb**

```
RSpec.describe PagesController, type: :controller do
  before :all do
    Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = true
    Rails.application.config.consider_all_request_local = false
  end

  describe "status 404" do
    it "respond with 404 if page is not found" do
      get :help, params: { id: "foobar" }
      expect(response.status).to eq(404)
    end
  end
end
```

The pages controller is simple and functions to render the static pages "/help" and "/about"

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def help
  end

  def about
  end
end
```

The error handling is set up as follows

**application_controller.rb**

```
 def not_found
   raise ActionController::RoutingError.new("Not Found")
 rescue
   render_404
 end

 def render_404
   render file: "#{Rails.root}/public/404", status: :not_found
 end
```

The test result is

```
expected: 404
            got: 200
```

Which I do not understand since "/help/foobar" does render the 404 page when I try it myself in the browser. I guess the problem could be that my "get" action in the test is formatted wrong but I'm not sure.

**EDIT**

**config/routes.rb** as requested

```
  get "/about", to: "pages#about"
  get "/help", to: "pages#help"
```

**EDIT 2**

Updated the test with the syntax from https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-4/docs/routing-specs/route-to-matcher

The test now looks like this

```
RSpec.describe PagesController, type: :controller do
  before :all do
    Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = true
    Rails.application.config.consider_all_request_local = false
  end

  describe "status 404" do
    it "respond with 404 if page is not found" do
      expect(get("/foobar")).to route_to("application#not_found")
    end
  end
end
```

Unfortuenly this raises another error

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
 No route matches {:action=>"/foobar", :controller=>"pages"}
```

No route is matching which is kind of the point but the "not_found" method is being used for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Change your routes to make your call work from the browser:

```ruby
get "/help/:id", to: "pages#help"
```

If the test returns a `200`, it's because it calls directly the `help` method from your controller without using the `config/routes.rb` file.

**EDIT**

Here is how you test your routing: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-4/docs/routing-specs/route-to-matcher

Comment: I thought that you cannot miss `config/routes/` if you want to access your controler method.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your sentence. In the `rspec`context, you never use the `routes.rb` file when you test a controller. In normal context (production for example), you always use the `routes.rb` file to resolve the action. And when nothing match, it returns a 404.

Comment: Look at the bottom of my answer (bellow the EDIT), you have a link to rspec explaining what you can do.

Comment: @romaninsalles Now I have rewritten the test after those displayed on the website you mentioned. That caused another error, explained it in an edit.

Comment: If you want to manage your 404 properly, do as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654826#answer-21658189. And now, you'll be able to write your specs as it was at the beginning of your question, but on the `ErrorsController` (not the `PagesController`)