# STRIPE ROR: No route matches charges/new error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am a newbie in ROR,

I am trying to integrate **stripe** in my ROR project using this link:
https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/rails

I have addded everything as they suggested by when I go to http://localhost:3000/charges/new route, it gives me following error:

```
No route matches charges/new error
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  mount API::Root => '/'

  # Getting unmatched routes
  get '*unmatched_route', to: 'application#raise_not_found'

  resources :charges

end
```

Here are the routes generated:

```
                   charges GET    /charges(.:format)                                           charges#index
                           POST   /charges(.:format)                                           charges#create
                new_charge GET    /charges/new(.:format)                                       charges#new
               edit_charge GET    /charges/:id/edit(.:format)                                  charges#edit
                    charge GET    /charges/:id(.:format)                                       charges#show
                           PATCH  /charges/:id(.:format)                                       charges#update
                           PUT    /charges/:id(.:format)                                       charges#update
                           DELETE /charges/:id(.:format)                                       charges#destroy
```

**charges_controller.rb**:

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    # Amount in cents
    @amount = 500

    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :email => params[:stripeEmail],
        :source => params[:stripeToken]
    )

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :customer => customer.id,
        :amount => @amount,
        :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
        :currency => 'usd'
    )

  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to 'new_charge_path'
  end
end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag charges_path do %>
  <article>
    <% if flash[:error].present? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <p><%= flash[:error] %></p>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <label class="amount">
      <span>Amount: $5.00</span>
    </label>
  </article>

  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
          data-description="A month's subscription"
          data-amount="500"
          data-locale="auto"></script>
<% end %>
```

Can anyone help, what I am missing on? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the output of `rake routes | grep charges`  and charges_controllers.rb content

Comment: sure, give me a sec

Comment: @Imran,
Can you check now?

Comment: Added, please check.

Comment: @CaptainJackSparrow did u create `new.html.erb` file ? Also, make sure to restart the server!!!

Comment: Yes I have that file, I restarted server.

Comment: Does word `raise_not_found` occurs anywhere in your app?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes, 'raise_not_found' it has commented defination in **/app/controllers/application_controller.rb** file.

Comment: Paste the snippet please, to make it a complete question.

Comment: @Imran Added the code.

Comment: "it has commented definition" - well, there's your problem. Why is it commented? Uncomment it.

Comment: My bad. I meant application_controller not new.html.rb

Comment: That link you found, it a) shows another method (`raise_not_found!`, not `raise_not_found`) and b) does not appear to be in any way related to the problem. As far as I can tell, it's just a random project, which happens to contain a similar word. I commend you for trying to research the problem, but you need to learn to find _relevant_ information. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I have uncommented it and tried the same URL http://localhost:3000/charges/new NOW IT REDIRECTS ME TO BASE URL which is http://localhost:3000/.

Comment: @CaptainJackSparrow: well, that's another problem, isn't it? If I were to guess, some of your `before_actions` are not finding what they expect to find.

Comment: I found `before_filter :set_cache_buster, :store_location, :authenticate_session` so I commented it, just to skip the check, now I get this error: `No route matches charges/new`.

Comment: @CaptainJackSparrow: simply commenting code rarely works. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Haha, That's not the case, the issue still persists, as when I do `rake routes | grep charges` I can see the routes and now it gives `No route matches charges/new` error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173739/discussion-between-captain-jack-sparrow-and-sergio-tulentsev).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a minor mistake in the code of routes file.

The below-mentioned code should be at the last of the routes file. [[Refernce]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368799/how-to-create-a-catch-all-route-in-ruby-on-rails) And I had added `resources :charges` code below that line, that was the reason I was getting above mentioned error.

```
# Getting unmatched routes
get '*unmatched_route', to: 'application#raise_not_found'
```

The code started to work when I changed the content of the **routes file** as:

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do

    mount API::Root => '/'


    resources :charges

    # Getting unmatched routes
    get '*unmatched_route', to: 'application#raise_not_found'


  end
```