# Hot to redirect "example.com/////" to just "example.com" in Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webrick

My goal is when user requests root (AND ONLY ROOT, other pages work fine) with something like:

```
http://domain.com/////
http://domain.com//////////////
http://domain.com//
```

app should **301 redirect** user to one and only correct:

```
http://domain.com/
```

I'm using **Webrick, rack-rewrite gem** and planning to host it on **Heroku**.
Please remember that i'm new in Rails.

**UPDATE** ======

**[Rails: redirect all unknown routes to root_url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132039/rails-redirect-all-unknown-routes-to-root-url?lq=1)
— this is totally different problem. They just redirect all unknown hosts to root. I have 404 working normally.**

My problem is that any amount of slashes works as homepage and URL has all of those slashes. I'm doing it for SEO to get rid of duplicates of homepage. I want it to work like here: http://netpeak.ua (try "netpeak.ua////////", you will be redirected to "netpeak.ua").

**UPDATE 2 - added content of routes.rb** ======

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :questions

  resources :feedbacks

  devise_for :users

  get '' => 'public#index'

  get '/agency' => 'public#about'
  get '/contact' => 'public#contact'
  get '/uslugi' => 'services#index'
  get '/portfolio' => 'projects#index'
  get '/uslugi/:id' => 'services#show'
  get '/portfolio/:id' => 'projects#show'

  resources :articles, param: :id
  resources :settings, as: 'home' #home so it doesn't go to another page

  namespace :admin do
    resources :articles, :users, :projects, :services, :feedbacks, :questions
    get '' => 'projects#index'
    get 'contact' => 'settings#contact'
    get 'feedback' => 'settings#feedback'
    get 'fininfo' => 'settings#fininfo'

    get 'calls' => 'settings#calls'
    get 'orders' => 'settings#orders'
    get 'letters' => 'settings#letters'
    get 'allquestions' => 'settings#allquestions'

    get 'projectsettings' => 'settings#projectsettings'
    get 'servicessettings' => 'settings#servicessettings'
    get 'aboutsettings' => 'settings#aboutsettings'
    get 'startpagesettings' => 'settings#startpagesettings'
    patch 'contact' => 'settings#update'
    patch 'feedback' => 'settings#update'
    patch 'fininfo' => 'settings#update'
    patch 'projectsettings' => 'settings#update'
    patch 'servicessettings' => 'settings#update'
    patch 'aboutsettings' => 'settings#update'
    patch 'startpagesettings' => 'settings#update'
  end

end
```

Comment: Have you tested it is actually not happening already?

Comment: Off course I Have tested.
aeroplan.herokuapp/com — try is yourself.

Comment: Could you show your routes - rails should redirect automatically.

Comment: I've updated question with routes.rb content.

Comment: The application you mentioned is working as expected.

`➜  ~  curl -I http://aeroplan.herokuapp.com/agency/////////////` returns a `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently` to `Location: http://aeroplan.herokuapp.com/agency/`

Comment: Oh, you've been trying to access to /agency/ and that what i've fixed.

PLEASE, EVERYBODY PAY ATTENTION HERE:
My problem IS ONLY ROOT of website. Startpage with only slashes after .com Everything else works just fine.