# Redirect PUT route to root_url automatically in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

The rails application I'm currently running is running on a domain for a former wordpress site which has hacked. Every once and a while I'll receive an routing error notification for a PUT that the website does not and should not support. Obviously, I can't prevent these requests from being made but I would like to handle them gracefully.

In my routes file I already have all unknown paths redirect to the `root_url` as noted in this [SO post on routing unknown requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132039/rails-redirect-all-unknown-routes-to-root-url) with the code:

```
match '*path' => redirect('/'),via: [:get, :post]  unless Rails.env.development?
```

Even with that, I still receive errors, like the following:

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [PUT] "/cmyks42567.txt"
```

How do I redirect this in the routes file without writing a controller to pass the specific url and redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally handle this with your webserver software.

If you're using Apache, you could use something like:

```
#public/htaccess
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^*.txt$ http://example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

---

If you wanted to handle it in the Rails routes, you'd be able to use a [redirect](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection):

```
#config/routes.rb
unless Rails.env.development?
   scope constraints: { format: 'txt' } do
      match '*path', to: redirect('/'), via: [:get, :post, :put]
   end
end
```

You'd have to make sure you are capturing *only* the routes you need to redirect, though.

The problem you have with your setup is that it will capture every route you send to your app, and redirect to `root`. In fact, this may end up causing an infinite recursion error.

My code above works only in production / staging (as yours).

It takes any `.txt` route passed through the `GET`, `POST` or `PUT` HTTP verbs, redirecting to the root path.

Answer (score 1):

You got it, just change the `:via` option to `[:put]`:

```
match '*path' => redirect('/'), via: [:put] unless Rails.env.development?
```

According to the Rails Guide (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints): "You can use the match method with the :via option to match multiple verbs at once:" The way yo wrote it you are only matching GET and POST requests.

After the change your code works as expected.